# Windows FTP Transfer

Tags: macos, ftp, window

Currently I am using XAMPP on a XP machine and FTP service is running with it. On the other end I am using a Mac. I tried to use Cyberduck and transfer a file into the FTP server it works fine; the orignal file is 104kb and after transfer there it remain as 104kb but the problem starts when I try to use CLI to do an FTP transfer.

Tranferring the same file, when I check on the server side, it becomes 106kb and it is a pdf file and I am not able to open it.

Does anyone have this same problem before? And how you manage to solve it?

Comment: Assuming CLI is command line interface.  Can you confirm what commands you used,  did you remember a bin command before the get?

Answer (score 4):

Change to the binary transfer mode using the 'bin' command.